# Javascript refresh another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two different pages both open in different tabs. On the first page I have a button, that when clicked page 2 will refresh. How can I make this possible with javascript? Any help will be much appreciated.
page1.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshpage2(){
location.reload();
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="refresh page 2" onClick=refreshpage2()">
```

Code above will refresh the page itself, what I want is reload page2 when button is clicked.

Comment: Please provide code... a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net) would be great! And, of course, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Are the pages on the same domain? Has one page opened the other?

Comment: [localStorage cross-window messaging](http://bens.me.uk/2013/localstorage-inter-window-messaging)

Comment: @Juhana yes they are on the same domain.

Comment: @clyde, what are you trying to do? Pushing a button to refresh another page is not a good workflow. Are you trying to submit a form on one page and have the changes show up on the other page?

Comment: I need this to work because I need to display updated values on database on page2 by refreshing it after form in page1 is submitted and values are saved on the database.

Answer (score 2):

If these two pages are under you'r control you can put an ajax listener on page2 (the one that should be refreshed) and on page 1 put an ajax sender to notice page2's ajax to refresh the page. read this:
http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/ajax/Ajax/Updater/

Answer (score 1):

I assumed the you have two windows that the first window open second window that used to modified data in first window. You must open second window with window.open(url,'','') function and then refresh first window with function window.opener.location.reload(true);

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is forbidden, because of security issues.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: It's an answer to the question (even if it's not true).

Comment: I would not be uploading these pages online, only on LAN.

Comment: @Juhana having an answer that simply says "No" is still an answer. This needs a source.

Comment: @clyde From the browser's point of view there's no difference (unless it's IE with its security zone shenanigans)

Comment: @Juhana yes but that's not the point, the question is how can I make this possible? regardless of the security issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you have reference to the page that you opened (second tab), you can use the reference to refresh the page.  window.open might not open a new tab as it is designed to open a new browser window but the concept should be the same.

```
var newtab = window.open(url, '_blank');
```

now as long as you have access to the variable (global variable) newtab, you can use it to control the new tab.

```
newtab.document.location.reload(true);
```